# Once again: Not convertible to UInt8

Tags: ios, swift, int, uint

I like Swift, but its number type conversion quirks are starting to drive me mad...
Why ist the following code resulting in a `LogLevel is not convertible to UInt8 error` (in the if statement)?

```
import Foundation;

enum LogLevel : Int
{
    case System = 0;
    case Trace = 1;
    case Debug = 2;
    case Info = 3;
    case Notice = 4;
    case Warn = 5;
    case Error = 6;
    case Fatal = 7;
}

class Log
{
    struct Static
    {
        static var enabled:Bool = true;
        static var filterLevel:LogLevel = LogLevel.System;
    }

    public class func trace(data:AnyObject!)
    {
        if (Static.filterLevel > LogLevel.Trace) {return;}
        println("\(data)");
    }
}
```

LogLevel of type Int should after all be equal to LogLevel of type Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> “Enumerations in Swift are first-class types in their own right. ”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.
>   https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewBook?id=881256329

So, an enumeration is *not* an int and it doesn't make sense to perform mathematical comparisons on it. You have associated raw values with your enumeration values so you need to use the `toRaw` and `fromRaw` functions to access the raw values.

```
public class func trace(data:AnyObject!)
{
    if (Static.filterLevel.toRaw() > LogLevel.Trace.toRaw()) {return;}
    println("\(data)");
}
```

Comment: Aha, thanks for the description! Still have to get used to treat Enums as first-class types whose raw type cannot be used directly.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html):

> Use the `toRaw` and `fromRaw` functions to convert between the raw value
>   and the enumeration value.

In your case:

```
if Static.filterLevel.toRaw() > LogLevel.Trace.toRaw() {
    return;
}
```